# Audio - Get Voltage Level from Sample [C++]

Tags: c++, matlab, audio

I need a way to get the voltage level from audio at each sample rate point.

For example, if I have an audio track in memory, is there a way of getting the voltage value at each sample point and print that to a separate memory buffer as an array of 2 columns, column 0 being the sample point, and column 1 being the voltage level at each sample [0].

Typical reading of 16bit audio voltage (+- 32767).

I have tried to do this by adding the audio into memory, and then trying to get sample by sample readings, but I have not been able to get this working. Any Ideas?

Thank You

Comment: What voltage are you interested in? Do you know the relationship between the values stored in the audio file and whatever voltage you want?

Comment: Just the amplitude value at each sample, if that is possible?

Comment: You have to know the VDC of your recorder. This should be listed on the specifications of the data-acquisition card. For 16-bit audio, the voltage will then be `sample * VDC/(2^16)`

Comment: If your VDC (or Vpp - voltage peak-to-peak) is 2V, this means the voltage reading goes from -1V to +1V, and any sample between (-32767, 32767) is mapped to (-1V, 1V).

Answer (score 0):

The [audioread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) function in Matlab is designed to do what you want. This code will load the audio data into the variable `y` as 16-bit integer values:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('sample-3s.wav','native');
plot(y)
```